# .Net smtp send with SmtpStatusCode - when should a retry occur?

Tags: .net, smtp

I have a service which sends email and stores the outbound email in a database.
I'm using .NET native Smtp class for email transmission.  I have an error flag which is set if the email failed delivery.

My service will periodically check for undelivered messages and try to re-send.  Under what circumstances should it retry to send the email? I've noted that even if the email address is incorrect it will throw an exception, but I want my service to ditch any invalid emails otherwise it will retry forever.

Basically, I want to catch the exception whereby there is a good chance the email can be re-delivered. I guess this would be only network errors rather than email accounts.
Which of the SmtpStatusCode would indicate worthy of retry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode.aspx

Comment: Be sure to follow backoff practices and stop sending to a gateway for a while (not just that one email). For example, a response 421 4.7.0 should prompt holding and retrying all messages to that gateway later.

Answer (score 8):

I'm trying to solve the exact same problem you are. The solution I came up involved about an hour of pouring through RFC2821 and interpreting it as best as I could. If you are interested you can find it here - http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

The big take-away from reading the RFC is that codes of the form `4yz` indicate a transient negative completion code, which warrants a retry. Codes of the form `5yz` indicate a permanent negative completion code, which you should NOT retry.

So the goal is to filter out recipients where a retry is warranted and where it isn't. All of the `5yz` codes can be interpreted as "don't retry" with the exception of 552, which some servers may erroneously send instead of 452. From there on out you need to decide:

- Is this a serious technical error (503 `BadCommandSequence`) which should cause your service to fail fast without retrying anything.

OR

- Is this a negative permanent completion code which only applies to a single recipient, in which case you just leave out the recipient in question and retry the send operation.

Thus, my approach is such:

- Handle the `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` and `SmtpFailedRecipientException`.
- Store all failed recipients into a list.
- For each failed recipient, call my special `HandleFailedRecipient()` method which interprets the SMTP code. If at any time that method returns `false` then this indicates a much more serious error and my service should just fail fast (without trying to resend the email).
- Otherwise, the method may or may not re-add the recipient (depending on the SMTP code).
- Finally, if the message still has any remaining recipients, try to resend.

Here is my method which interprets the SMTP code:

```
    private bool HandleFailedRecipient(MailMessage message, string emailAddress, SmtpStatusCode statusCode, AddressType addressType)
    {            
        //Notify any event subscribers that a recipient failed and give them the SMTP code.
        RecipientFailedOnSend(this, new MailAddressEventArgs() { Address = emailAddress, AddressType = addressType, StatusCode = statusCode });

        //5yz codes typically indicate a 'Permanent Negative Completion reply', which means we should NOT keep trying to send the message.
        //The codes below can be interpreted as exceptions to the rule. In these cases we will just strip the user and try to resend.
        if (statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable ||              //550 = "No such user"
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxNameNotAllowed ||           //553 = "User name ambiguous"
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.UserNotLocalTryAlternatePath ||    //551 = "Mail address not deliverable"
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed)                 //554 = "Transaction failed / no valid recipients"
        {
            return true;
        }

        //The 4yz codes are 'Transient Negative Completion reply' codes, which means we should re-add the recipient and let the calling routine try again after a timeout.
        if (statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ServiceNotAvailable ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.LocalErrorInProcessing ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.InsufficientStorage ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ClientNotPermitted ||
//The ones below are 'Positive Completion reply' 2yz codes. Not likely to occur in this scenario but we will account for them anyway.
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.SystemStatus ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.HelpMessage ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ServiceReady ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ServiceClosingTransmissionChannel ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.Ok ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.UserNotLocalWillForward ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.CannotVerifyUserWillAttemptDelivery ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.StartMailInput ||
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.CannotVerifyUserWillAttemptDelivery ||
            //The code below (552) may be sent by some incorrect server implementations instead of 452 (InsufficientStorage).
            statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ExceededStorageAllocation)
        {
            if ((addressType & AddressType.To) != 0)
            {
                message.To.Add(emailAddress);
            }
            if ((addressType & AddressType.CC) != 0)
            {
                message.CC.Add(emailAddress);
            }
            if ((addressType & AddressType.BCC) != 0)
            {
                message.Bcc.Add(emailAddress);
            }
            return true;
        }

        //Anything else indicates a very serious error (probably of the 5yz variety that we haven't handled yet). Tell the calling routine to fail fast.
        return false;
    }
```

Let me know if this makes sense or if you need to see more code, but it should be relatively clear-cut from here.

Comment: Hey, do you think you can license this code under MIT? Thanks!